# Closing HDF5 file in seperate thread throws Access Violation exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, hdf5

I'm currently using the HDF.PInvoke package for .Net to write incoming data into sequential 1GB files. Due to the high-throughput nature of the application, I want to reduce the time spent closing and creating a new file to avoid any potential buffer overflow. When I ran tests in a single thread, releasing the file's resources could take up to 2 seconds,so I thought I would run this part of the operation in a seperate thread, which would leave the main thread free to create a new file and start writing data again.

Here is the code:

```
// create dataspace 
var dataspace_id = H5S.create_simple(dataSpaceRank, dataSpaceDimensions, null);

while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {


        // ****** OPEN FILE ******



        // update filename
        fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yy") + "_Sparrow_DUT" + fileHead.chipID + "_" + fileHead.chipType + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm") + "_" + fileHead.fileNum + ".h5";


        // create new file
        var file_id = H5F.create(Path.Combine(capturePath, fileName), H5F.ACC_TRUNC);



        // create dataset
        var dataset_id = H5D.create(file_id, "/capture_data", H5T.NATIVE_INT16, dataspace_id,
                        H5P.DEFAULT, dcpl, H5P.DEFAULT);




        // ****** START WRITING DATA ******


        while (packetsWritten <= packetsPerFile)
        {

            // select the subset of the dataspace the packet is to be written to
            status = H5S.select_hyperslab(dataspace_id, H5S.seloper_t.SET, offset, stride, count, block);

            // write dataset 
            status = H5D.write(dataset_id, H5T.NATIVE_INT16, memspace_id, dataspace_id, H5P.DEFAULT, dataPointer.AddrOfPinnedObject());

            // increment number of packets written
            packetsWritten++;

            // update the selection parameters
            offset[1] = packetsWritten * (ulong)fileHead.packetLen;

        }



        // ****** CLOSE FILE ******



        // close the file in a seperate thread (this operation delays the application the most)
        Task cleanUp = Task.Run(() => CleanUpHDF5Writer(dataset_id, file_id));



        // reset the offset
        offset[1] = 0;

        // reset packets written for new file
        packetsWritten = 0;



    }
```

Where:

```
private void CleanUpHDF5Writer(long dataset_id, long file_id)
    {

        // close dataset and release its resources
        H5D.close(dataset_id);

        // close file and release its resources
        H5F.close(file_id);

    }
```

An Access Violation Exception is thrown after a few files are written - usually in the CleanUpHDF5Writer function, but sometimes also when the hyperslab is being selected. I can't figure out why this is happening, as the new file shouldn't access the same resources as the old one (as far as I can tell);

Any help with this greatly appreciated :)

Comment: UPDATE: seems to have been fixed by increasing the chunk size, which reduces the time spent closing the file. In turn, it means that there is less of a chance that the close functions will interfere with other resources.

Comment: UPDATE2: actually this didn't work